# No carga MySQL WorkBench: "No Connection"

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

Al ingresar al local instance:

[image]

Ya no me pide la contraseña y aparece en rojo "NO CONNECTION" como se puede ver
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien traté de importar un nuevo modelo entidad relación desde DataBase/Forward Engineer y aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías intentar ir al Administrador de Tareas, y ver los Servicios. Buscar por MySQL Server, y reiniciarlos

Comment: Seguro que instalaste el motor de base de datos?, el workbench es solo el manejador. No se ve el status del server.

Comment: Revisa quer el servicio de mysql que este corriendo en "Servicios", puedes acceder del menu de inicio. si no esta inslado no te funcionara, ademas de que si tienes otra instalacion independiente tipo xamp, igual dara problemas.

Answer (score 0):

1. Podrías dirigirte a

> C:\Archivos de programa\MySQL\MySQL Server (###version)\bin
>
> ejecutar la herramienta "MySQLInstanceConfig.exe"

Configurar la instalación de nuevo, o también

2. Reiniciar los servicios correspondientes a MySQL, como te había mencionado en mi comentario.

El manual nos dice lo siguiente:

> *"The error (2003) Can't connect to MySQL server on 'server' (10061) indicates that the network connection has been refused. You should
>   check that there is a MySQL server running, that it has network
>   connections enabled, and that the network port you specified is the
>   one configured on the server."*
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

Answer (score 0):

Verifica los servicios de Windows y reinicia el de MySQL, también podrías ser error e que el puerto este siendo ocupado, en su defecto cambia el puerto de servicio, estas usando el 3306, intenta colocar el 3307